# Assigning a variable to a wrapper set in jQuery doesn't make the code work

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I am trying to cache or to assign my selector `$('#img-grp-wrap .img-wrap img:first-child')` to a variable because I used it a lot of times in the code and I kept on repeating myself. But for some reason, when I assigned my selection to a variable, the code doesn't work anymore. Please see below (1st one is working, 2nd one not working):

Non-cached (working):

http://jsfiddle.net/g5tvZ/

Cached (not working):

http://jsfiddle.net/uMe2p/

(The code is supposed to automatically slide through the images and be able to use next/prev buttons to navigate. Please ignore the extra `var rotate;` on top. I would also appreciate any other refactoring tips about the code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
var imgFirst = $('#img-grp-wrap .img-wrap img:first-child');
```

leaves a set of DOM elements (along with jQuery wrapping) in `imgFirst`. Your `imgFirst` will match the state of the DOM when you assign your value to `imgFirst`.

Then later you change the DOM so `:first-child` doesn't select the same element that it used to and you're left with the wrong thing in `imgFirst`. Basically, the DOM changes but your `imgFirst` doesn't track those changes.

Comment: If that's the case, how do I cache that selector? Or if I would just cache $('#img-grp-wrap .img-wrap img) to imgFirst, how do I filter it using :first-child. Is this allowed: imgFirst:first-child.append() (etc.) ?

Comment: Never mind, I realized I can use imgFirst.filter(:first-child). Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: @cat: You'd have to cache each of the image elements in its own `$()` wrapper and keep track of which is the first by hand. Probably not worth the effort just for a slideshow. You could try cacheing `var $wrap = $('#img-grp-wrap .img-wrap')` and do `$wrap.find('img:first-child')` to get the first one.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did (see my reply). I used filter. Working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out another issue you have with your code.  You need to remove the `var` from in front of the `rotate` assignment here so that you are assigning to the same global variable that keeps track of your timer.  With the `var` in front of it, it's a local variable and you will get multiple timers stacking up when you repeatedly click on the prev or next buttons (which it's possible to make happen).  So change this:

```
$('#img-grp-wrap .prev, #img-grp-wrap .next').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(rotate);
}, function() {
   var rotate = setInterval(function() {
        slideShow();
    }, 4000);
});
```

to this:

```
$('#img-grp-wrap .prev, #img-grp-wrap .next').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(rotate);
}, function() {
    rotate = setInterval(function() {
        slideShow();
    }, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I removed that on the code I'm using. I think I forgot to remove it when I copied the timer.